# How to solve NaN sum a column in an HTML Table

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I wounder if anyone could help?
 I'm stuck with this and I know that I'm close but need help to figure out how to debug this.

I have this table that gets values from a sheet to HTML page onLoad="reloadTable()"

Everything works, except when I try to sum a column and that's when I get the Sum Value = NaN
in my  instead of the calculation.

I know that it works if I hard code the table on to the HTML file, not when it dynamically loads it from the sheet.

I have checked the formatting to see if I indeed have numbers
I've removed my table headers 
i've changed the CODE.GS script to getValues() instead of getDisplayValues()
Nothing works.
If I remove the parseInt() it will return a string of the numbers of column [2]
like so
Sum Value = 05816111120

This is the function that I'm having a problem with.

```
function sum() {
        var table = document.getElementById("table1"), sumVal = 0;
        for(var i = 1; i < table.rows.length; i++)
        {
            sumVal = sumVal + parseInt(table.rows[i].cells[2].innerHTML);
        }
        document.getElementById("val").innerHTML = "Sum Value = " + sumVal;
        console.log(sumVal);
}
```

table view

[table1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dAiBY.png)

This is how my table gets loaded which works fine

```
<script>
function reloadTable() {
          google.script.run.withSuccessHandler( function (table) {
         document.getElementById("ParcelCurrentClientCurrentInvoice").innerHTML = table;// pass table data to HTML

setTimeout(sum,2000);// run func. to sum column 3 of loaded table after 2 seconds

}
).getTable();//get data table from sheet server side

 }
</script>
```

serverSide.GS

```
 function getTable() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1ZawJJjI-Xhfgsdfgdfgsdfgsdfgsdfg").getSheetByName("RequisicaoConsolidationList");
   //var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
   var lastRow = getLastPopulatedRow(sheet); 
  var data = sheet.getRange(4,7,lastRow,4).getDisplayValues();
  var table = "<table id='table1' border='0' ><tr> <th>ID</th> <th>DATA</th> <th>QTD</th> <th>VALOR</th><th><input type='checkbox' name='check-All' onchange='checkAlltable1()' ></th> </tr>";
   //<td><input type='checkbox' /></td>
  for( var i=0; i<data.length; i++ ) {
    table = table.concat("<tr>");
    for( var j=0; j<data[0].length; j++ ) {
      table = table.concat("<td>");
      table = table.concat(data[i][j].toString());
      table = table.concat("</td>");
    }  

    table = table.concat("<td><input type='checkbox' name='check-tab1'></td></tr>");
     }
     table= table.concat("</table>");
  Logger.log(table);
  return table;
}
```

Comment: Stick a bit of console logging in to see what values it's trying to add.  I suspect that you're getting valid numbers most of the time, but then try to add a string.  Looking at the table it may be the bottom rows that are empty that are causing you the problem.  Alternatively, check that the innerHtml != "" first, before you add it.

Comment: @Archer, you rock, you were correct the last ghost rows were the problem. I subtracted them from the for loop like so: data.length-2; and it worked. Is there a way to tell the script to ignore those empty row or cell? What do you mean by "check that the innerHTML != "" " are you refering to placing an if statement in the code? 
The other thing is that my row has numbers after the decimal points ei: 150.15  +  10.10 should = 160.25 but instead it rounds it down to 160 
I used  sumVal.toFixed(2); but that only add the  .00 to my result like this 160.00
Maybe this should be another question.

Comment: Glad that helped.  And yes, I meant just put an if statement in to check that the value is not NaN before adding it.  Also, use `parseFloat()` to parse non-integer numbers.  I'll wrap this up in an answer for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you've got is that you're getting to empty cells and trying to add the numeric value of them, which in turn makes the whole sum become `NaN`.  You can check the value before adding it, like this...

```
// get the cell value
var cellValue = table.rows[i].cells[2].innerHTML;

// check that the value is a number before adding it to the total
if (!isNaN(cellValue)) {
    sumVal = sumVal + parseFloat(cellValue);
}
```

As per your later comment, I also used `parseFloat()` since the numbers are not always integers.